# Interpreting standard error for dummy variables in linear regression models

Tags: regression, interpretation, standard-error, categorical-encoding

Is there any way to interpret the standard error of dummy variables created to represent a categorical variable in a linear regresion model? I saw a great mathematical explanation [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/234727/standard-errors-of-regression-coefficients-in-a-dummy-variable-regression-model), but I am still having trouble with the "real-life" interpretation, if any.

As an example, let's say that this is the result of a case study:

```
> summary(results)$coefficients

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  31.35750    2.32037  13.514 1.55e-14 ***
sexwoman     -0.53100    1.77624  -0.299   0.7670
```

Representing the average sallary of employees of a company (in thousands) based on their sex. How would we interpret this standard error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The underlying math is that the intercept ($\beta_0$) indicates the average salary of men, in \$1000; the parameter $\beta_1$ indicates the *difference* between the average woman's and average man's salary.  So we could say something like "on average, women make \$530 less than men (with a standard error of \$1,776)". The $\pm 2 \mbox{SE}$ confidence intervals on the difference range from women's salaries being \$2,306 less to \$1,246 more than men's.

$\pm 2 \textrm{SE}$ is a commonly used shortcut; it is a little wider than the Normal-based 95% confidence interval ($\pm 1.96 \textrm{SE}$) and is a good approximation when your residual degrees of freedom (number of observations minus the number of model parameters) is *moderate*. In particular, the SE multiplier (which is can be computed in R via `qt(0.975, df)` for a given `df`) is:

- 1.96 (actually 1.9599) as df $\to \infty$
- 2.008 for df = 50
- 2.086 for df = 20
- 2.228 for df = 10
- 2.571 for df = 5.

and so on. The SE multiplier that I back-calculated from your comments is approximately 2.6, so my guess is that you had *approximately* 5 residual df (the residual df are displayed in the `summary()` output, but you haven't shown us ...)

Interpreting dummy variables associated with factors can get considerably more complicated when different contrasts, and interactions among predictors, are present, but your case is simple.

Comment: I see. And this confidence interval is not related to the 95% confidence interval that we get from confint(results), correct?

Comment: No, it's approximately the same as what you get from `confint(results)`.  Rather than use $\pm 2 \textrm{SE}$, `confint` will use a multiplier based on a t distribution with the residual degrees of freedom (number of observations - 2 in this case) , which will be only **approximately** equal to 2.

Comment: This does not really agree with my data, as `>confint(results)` results in the following:

2.5 % 97.5 %

(Intercept) 26.625080 36.0899220

sexwoman -4.153664 3.0916739<br>

However, this may be due to the fact that I had some more variebles in this case study that i did not want to bother you with.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Just read the edit. So helpful. Thank you very much!